# Rails ENV variable inside Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

How can I read ENV variable

```
module MyModule
  def self.current_ip
    request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
  end
end

MyModule::current_ip
```

How to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are referencing the request object that doesn't exist in the module scope.
You need to pass it or store it somewhere.

```
module MyModule
  mattr_accessor :request
  def self.current_ip
    request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
  end
end

# store the request using a before filter
# or similar approach
MyModule.request = request

MyModule::current_ip
```

Depending on your case, there might be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

why not just `ENV['REMOTE_ADDR']`?

Comment: Hmm- it should be accessible from anywhere if set correctly- this guide has a few different options: http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html